# What is the difference between a stage, and build in Jenkins pipelines?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Example:

---using stage------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
stage 'myjob'

node('mynode'){
    echo "i am in stage"
}
```

--using build job------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
build job: 'myjob',
 parameters: [
 [$class: 'NodeParameterValue',

  name: 'NODE_NAME',

  labels: 'mynode', 

  nodeEligibility: [$class: 'AllNodeEligibility']],
```

Comment: From the Jenkins book: A stage block defines a conceptually distinct subset of tasks performed through the entire Pipeline (e.g. "Build", "Test" and "Deploy" stages), which is used by many plugins to visualize or present Jenkins Pipeline status/progress.

Comment: so you are saying "stage" is just for the view?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea, I just copied the text from the book.  You can go and read about it yourself in the Jenkins documentation if you like.  But from the text that I copied it looks to me like it is a block containing multiple distinct tasks, one of which might be a build task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Stage](https://jenkins.io/doc/tutorials/build-a-java-app-with-maven/#create-your-initial-pipeline-as-a-jenkinsfile) describes a stage of this Pipeline. It is used in the visualization in the `Stage View` in a job overview page (Jenkins UI). It is basically just a name.
- [build](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/) is a `Pipeline Step` which triggers a new build for a given job.
  For example `build job: 'myjob', parameters: [ [$class: 'NodeParameterValue',..` `myjob` - name of a downstream job to build, `parameters` - some parameters for this build.